# Game Engine - Steering Behaviour Understanding

Tags: game-engine, physics, tracking, logic-bricks, path

I am working on a **BGE Horror Game** right now and I want the enemy to **follow the player around**, but not directly. I want it to also **walk around radon parts** of the map even when the player is not there. Is this any possible with the **Steering Actuator?** And also, I have seen the **different behaviours** that I can apply (**Path following, Seek, Flee)**. What is the **difference** between these 3?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to BSE! :D As far as following the player around, I think you'll have to do a bit of work in python for that.  I would suggest having the enemy path find to an empty that is placed randomly via a python script.  As far as the different behaviors go, from what I can remember path following has obstacle avoidance and is a good way to get from point A to point B.  Seek will cause the object to just start walking towards the target, and flee will cause it to start walking away.  I believe seek and flee have basic obstacle avoidance, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Possible result:
[image]

---

What you're searching for is called a "**Navmesh**" and it is done without any python-code.

Therefore you need the **Steering-Actuator**.

The ***Seek-Mode*** makes your object to allways face into the direction of the target and move towards it, until the set distance is reached.

The ***Flee-Mode*** is quite the opposite, it makes your object move away from the target, until the set distance is reached.

What you need for avoiding obstacles is the ***Path following-Mode***. This mode uses a mesh that tells your object, where it can move and calculates the fastest way to the target.

---

**1. Create a Navmesh** - select every collision objects in your scene, including the floor. Then click on <kbd>Build Navigation Mesh</kbd>, which creates you a plane with holes, where your obstacles are. Play around with the Agent-Values if your scene has ramps or different hights...

[image]

**2. Use the Navmesh** by choosing your Navmesh as "Navigation Mesh" in your Steering-Actuator.